# Customize Web Api Error message when url not matched

Tags: api, iis, asp.net-web-api2

I have a web api which host on IIS and it's allowed to access via internet. When I input wrong parameter in request url, it shows the ip address of api server rather than its address. 
Example: I host api on abc.com. I access the api by abc.com/api/myapi?par=kk
when i request wrong api it shows `No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'https://10.10.10.10/api/myapi` I want it to show like `abc.com/api/myapi`
Is there any config on web api or IIS?

Answer (score 1):

You can set a custom Not Found page in the Global.asax

```
protected void Application_EndRequest()
{
    if (Context.Response.StatusCode == 404)
    {
     var urlRef = Context.Request.Url;
     Response.Clear();

     //Set your route details here 
     var routedata = new RouteData();
     routedata.Values["controller"] = "Home";//Your controller
     routedata.Values["action"] = "Index";// Your action

     //Redirect to not found page or login page
     //Sample logic
     IController c = new HomeController();
     c.Execute(new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(Context), routedata));
    }
}
```

Use custom view so what ever you want to show will be in your view